# Como tratar o fechamento não usual da lista de um ComboBox no VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, combobox

Estou criando um efeito importante para a apresentação de um **ComboBox** em particular.

O texto deste ComboBox está originalmente **centralizado**, e ao abrir a sua lista faço com que o texto seja **alinhado à esquerda** para que os itens de sua lista sejam apresentados **alinhados à esquerda**, mas a ideia é que o texto da caixa do ComboBox permanecesse **centralizado**. Como *não é possível fazer isso apenas com o próprio **ComboBox***, encontrei uma forma de fazer:

Um "Label" com o mesmo texto do ComboBox e também **centralizado** tem a dimensão aproximada deste ComboBox e **torna-se visível sobre ele** quando o ComboBox é selecionado, e isto é feito por meio do evento "Enter".

Assim, o usuário **vê o texto centralizado no ComboBox** uma vez que o Label esconde o texto original que está alinhado à esquerda pelo evento "Enter", e **a lista é apresentada** automaticamente por meio do "DropDown" **alinhada à esquerda**. Até ai, perfeito!

Preparei o evento "Click" do Label para o caso do usuário "clicar" sobre ele ao invés de selecionar um item, então, o Label "seria removido" (**ficando invisível**) e **a lista seria fechada**, porém, neste caso ***a lista NÃO é fechada, mas o Label é removido***, precisando então dar um "clique" sobre o ComboBox para que a lista feche (neste momento o texto do ComboBox volta a ser centralizado).

**Caso houvesse um controle sobre o "fechamento da lista"**, quando o Label é  removido no primeiro "clique" a lista seria fechada, mas nas pesquisas não encontrei nada que pudesse usar ou solucionar o problema.

**Há alguma forma de controle sobre o fechamento da lista do ComboBox no VBA, ou uma outra forma de criar este efeito?**

O código para verificação é esse:

```
Private Sub UserForm_activate()

ComboBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter

ComboBox1.AddItem "Primeiro"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Segundo"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Terceiro"
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0

Label1.Left = ComboBox1.Left + 2
Label1.Width = ComboBox1.Width - 4
Label1.Top = ComboBox1.Top + 2
Label1.Height = ComboBox1.Height - 2

Label1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter

Label1.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone

Label1.ZOrder 0

Label1.Visible = False

TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_enter()

ComboBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft

Label1 = ComboBox1.Text

Label1.Visible = True

ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub


Private Sub Label1_Click()

ComboBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter

Label1.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o <code> Private Sub Combobox_Change() </code>? Pode ser que dê certo.

Comment: Oi Evert, o Change não é acionado pois não há a seleção de um item na lista.

Comment: Entendi @Leo... complicado... tem como enviar a planilha para dar  uma olhada ou o código que está usando?

Comment: Penso que se fizer um refresh no formulário talvez? Gravando e buscando as informações já inseridas...

Comment: Houve um engano e alterei partes do texto, pois na verdade o que ocorre é o oposto do que descrevi, o Label é removido, mas a lista permanece aberta.

Comment: Acho que entendi o que quer... creio que a sequência dos códigos precisa ser ajustada. Um minuto que vou montar aqui pra testar.

Comment: Alterei o código também, estava com os alinhamentos invertidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução possível seria utilizar o *change*:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

ComboBox1.AddItem "Primeiro"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Segundo"
ComboBox1.AddItem "Terceiro"
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0

Label1.Left = ComboBox1.Left + 2
Label1.Width = ComboBox1.Width - 4
Label1.Top = ComboBox1.Top + 2
Label1.Height = ComboBox1.Height - 2
Label1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
Label1.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
Label1.ZOrder 0
Label1 = ComboBox1.Text
Label1.Visible = False
TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_enter()

Label1 = ComboBox1.Text
Label1.Visible = True

ComboBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
ComboBox1.DropDown
ComboBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Label1 = ComboBox1.Text
Label1.Visible = False

ComboBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Se precisar pode utilizar o *AfterUpdate* também para qualquer resolução após a atualização:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

End Sub
```

---

Outra opção seria usar um ListBox e um Label, daí configura o layout do Label para ficar como quiser de forma a parecer um ComboBox, segue exemplo:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

ListBox1.AddItem "Primeiro"
ListBox1.AddItem "Segundo"
ListBox1.AddItem "Terceiro"
ListBox1.ListIndex = 0

ListBox1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter

Label1.Left = ListBox1.Left + 2
Label1.Width = ListBox1.Width - 4
Label1.Top = ListBox1.Top + 2
Label1.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
Label1.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
Label1.ZOrder 0
Label1 = ListBox1.Text
ListBox1.Visible = False
Label1.Visible = True

TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

Label1.Visible = False
ListBox1.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Label1 = ListBox1.Text
ListBox1.Visible = False
Label1.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Veja se assim funciona melhor.

Abs,

Comment: @Leo veja se dessa forma te ajuda. O único problema é que se a pessoa usar o teclado ela somente poderá mudar uma vez com a seta... mas creio que consegue-se solucionar isso com uma verificação de KeyDown ou KeyPress. Não tive tempo de testar essa parte. Me avise se assim atende. Abs

Comment: Outra opção também pode ser uma ListBox ao invés de um combo box... já que não está utilizando as funções do ComboBox de fato. Talvez seja até melhor utilizar o ListBox, não?

Comment: Leo mas vc não clicaria sobre o label... pensei que ele ficaria escondido sempre ele só se mostra quando o usuário abre o combobox, não?

Comment: Pode colocar um Click no Label para colocar o foco no TextBox1 e utilize o after update para fazer com que o label suma se for o caso. Estou fazendo o listBox para testar e vou postar aqui tb.

Comment: Veja se assim fica melhor.. acho que será mais fácil com o ListBox

Comment: Segue um exemplo que fiz: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7A3D691330A912A!208644&authkey=!AEcRINedfXtZM90&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: Evert, o primeiro código funcionou! Porém, para ficar completo é preciso colocar o evento Click do Label, passando o foco para o TextBox (eu tiraria o evento Change, pois funciona sem ele), fazendo esta edição fica perfeita a resposta. Grato pela planilha e esforço, vou marcar a resposta após edição. Abraço.

Comment: Leo, não fiz um teste aqui e ok para ficar correta a resposta... mas se o usuário ao invés de clicar utilizar o teclado ainda assim funciona? Não consegui reproduzir aqui o efeito que comentou...

Comment: Leo, Coloquei na mesma pasta um arquivo com o ComboBox... não consegui reproduzir para ficar de maneira funcional tanto com mouse quanto com o teclado, setas etc... se puder dar uma olhada no arquivo que fiz... acho que o ListBox ficou melhor. Mas talvez no seu contexto não seja a melhor opção.

Comment: Sim, funcionou parcialmente, mas complementei. Ao entrar com o "Tab" a lista é aberta e ao "clicar" sobre o Label a lista fecha, mas se usar o "ESC" com a lista aberta ou teclar algo, o Label permanece, então solucionei com o evento KeyPress no ComboBox, adicionando  KeyAscii = 0  e chamando  Label1_Click  e depois criei o evento Exit  somente chamando o  Label1_Click,  FUNCIONOU! Se quiser acrescer ao código ficará 10! Abraço.